# Keynote transition delay time for each slide

Tags: keynote

I am working with Keynote for the first time to create a slideshow.  I have a slideshow with just over 200 slides in it and I need the last 2 slides (one of which is a short 20 second video clip) to show for longer than the rest, which show 7.5 seconds.  How do you customize single slides to stay longer before they transition without changing the entire slideshow?

I am using Keynote Version 6.2 
Software is OS X Version 10.9.5

Answer (score 3):

In the **Animate** inspector tab you will find all the settings to easily change transition timing. You can do so for each slide or for the entire slideshow. In the movie inspector you can view the movie length then change your slide transition accordingly. 
I encourage you to explore the user interface. Create a new slideshow just to play with. Then start clicking buttons and menu items. See what stuff does. Just like driving a new car, new software can take a little getting used to but in the long run, a little time invested will pay off. Cheers.

[image: Transition timing]

Answer (score 2):

Select the video.
Go to View > Inspector > Animate.
In the 'Build In' tab click on 'Build Order' at the bottom.
In the pop up window select Start: After Transition, Delay: 0 seconds.
In the 'Build Out' tab click on 'Add an Effect'. Select 'Stop Movie'.
(If you had closed the pop up window click on 'Build Order' again)
Start After Build 1, Delay: insert as many seconds as the movie is long.
Go to the previous slide and test it. (Play > Play Slideshow).
The normal slide transition delay is added at the end of the movie before the next slide appears.

Screenshot of pop up window:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Screenshot of pop up window:

[image]

:)

Comment: Hi Carolin, I think it would be better to edit your first answer instead of adding a second one.